# How to align row with text and two icons in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a Row that will have an icon and then text and then another icon in the most left part of the row. I tried some solutions that I found online but none of them worked. Someone know how can I do this like in the picture below? (if it's even possible).
**this is what I want to create:**

[image]

> You can show me how to do one row and I will duplicate it.

**this is the code I have tried already:**

```
            // Edit profile button...
            Padding( // make it the same size of the edit profile button. (horizontally wise)
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                left: size.width * .048,
                top: size.height * .007,
                right: size.width * .048,
              ),
              child: Column( // creating column for all three rows.
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: size.height * .04, // give the Container height (one row)
                    color: NotificationColor,
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Wrap( // create the first icon and the text in wrap so the whole three of the rows will have the same space between the icon and the text. 
                          spacing: size.width * .07,
                          children: [
                            Icon( // creating the first icon.
                              CupertinoIcons.bell,
                              size: size.width * .06,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                            Padding( // the text wasn't center vertically wise so I used padding to make him be.
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                0,
                                04,
                                0,
                                0,
                              ),
                              child: Text( // the text of the row.
                                "Notification",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: size.width * .04,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Align( // here I am trying to make the third icon in the most left size of the row (in the edge of the edit profile border). but it's not working.
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                            size: size.width * .04,
                            color: const Color(
                              0xA6A6A6A6,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  // and this is supposed to be the other two rows.
                  SizedBox(height: size.height * .01),
                  Container(),
                  SizedBox(height: size.height * .01),
                  Container(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

**and this is what I got instead:**

[image]

Someone show me a better way to make it work?.

> The edit profile button is great (no need to touch).

Comment: Its better you go with the ```ListTile```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a `Spacer()` between the 'Notification' text and the forward arrow icon.

```dart
// Edit profile button...
            Padding( // make it the same size of the edit profile button. (horizontally wise)
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                left: size.width * .048,
                top: size.height * .007,
                right: size.width * .048,
              ),
              child: Column( // creating column for all three rows.
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: size.height * .04, // give the Container height (one row)
                    color: NotificationColor,
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Wrap( // create the first icon and the text in wrap so the whole three of the rows will have the same space between the icon and the text. 
                          spacing: size.width * .07,
                          children: [
                            Icon( // creating the first icon.
                              CupertinoIcons.bell,
                              size: size.width * .06,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                            Padding( // the text wasn't center vertically wise so I used padding to make him be.
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                0,
                                04,
                                0,
                                0,
                              ),
                              child: Text( // the text of the row.
                                "Notification",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: size.width * .04,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Spacer(),
                        Align( // here I am trying to make the third icon in the most left size of the row (in the edge of the edit profile border). but it's not working.
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                            size: size.width * .04,
                            color: const Color(
                              0xA6A6A6A6,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  // and this is supposed to be the other two rows.
                  SizedBox(height: size.height * .01),
                  Container(),
                  SizedBox(height: size.height * .01),
                  Container(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can used **`ListTile`** Widget also.

Refer [**`ListTile`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html)

Try below code hope its help to you.

```
ListTile(
  leading: Icon(
    CupertinoIcons.bell,
  ),
  title: Text(
    'Notifications',
  ),
  trailing: Icon(
    Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
  ),
),
```

Your result screen using **`ListTile`**-> [image]

You also used [`Spacer`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Spacer-class.html) Widget, put this Widget in below Structure

```
Row(
      children: [
        Icon(
          CupertinoIcons.bell,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 10,
        ),
        Text(
          'Notifications',
        ),
        Spacer(),
        Icon(
          Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Your Result Screen using **`Spacer`** -> [image]